# WebRequest SecurityException

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain-policy

I am trying to post a cross-domain HTTP request but keep getting a SecurityException instead of a response.

I have added a *clientaccesspolicy.xml*:

```
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

aswell as a *crossdomain.xml*:

```
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

to the silverlight app and set both to *content + copy always*.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the xml files exist on the **root** of the sites? Maybe you could let Fiddler or any other network monitor run while attempting to access the service, this way you can see a 404 to the xml files and see where it goes wrong.

edit: also, you only need a clientaccesspolicy.xml if you are using Silverlight. The crossdomain.xml is a flash based domain policy file which Silverlight also understands.

Comment: I am working localy atm. Do these files need to exist on the target?

Comment: Yes, they should. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: so it is not possible to access any resources located on other domains then my own when I use silverlight? As said the xml files exist.

Comment: Correct, just ask the webservice owners to place a file in the root on their service.

Comment: If you can access the service (e.g. http webservice) over browser (get methode) you could also use a proxy to access that service which has no policyfile.